# Is there a way to slow down the speed of the screen on purpose in Android?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-screen, layout-inspector

I have an issue that TextView's content vibrates up and down in a moment. 
it looks like turns WRAP_CONTENT into MATCH_PARENT, but i'm not sure. 
so i want to see it slowly how to change the Texview's content.
is there a option to slow down the speed of screen animation or is there a function in layout inspector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with *Developer Options*, like here: https://trendblog.net/android-device-animations/